# Get a string after a specific substring in Julia

Tags: julia

How can I find the next sub string if specific string would appear in Julia ?

For example I have this string:

```
push constant 17
```

I want to find (and then print) 17

Alternatively how can I move x characters from the beginning of a line and select an expected string from this position ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `regex` matching? If so, you can do the following:

```
julia> my_string = "push constant 17"
"push constant 17"
```

You can search in this string and capture the `17` by doing a positive lookbehind in regex. What this means is that you are looking for the values after a certain string. You can speify this behaviour by setting `?<=` before the string you're looking for. `\d+` just captures the digits after the lookbehind:

```
julia> my_matches = match(r"(?<=push constant )(\d+)", my_string)
RegexMatch("17", 1="17")
```

Then extract the match by accessing the `match` field:

```
julia> my_matches.match
"17"
```